GitHub Desktop not ignoring the file added to ignore. The all files showing in Commit Changes list
I am using the latest version of GitHub Desktop. I am trying to ignore some files like .pdb, .dll, and other unnecessary files, but these files are still being added to the commit changes list. The changes I make to the .gitignore file are not being reflected; it shows all files as they are.
I tried changing the .gitignore file and checked with another repository, but it showed the same result. I also tried to reinstall the GitHub Desktop but no luck.
I expect that when I add any file to the ignore list, it should be ignored and not show up in the commit changes list.

With you posting the .gitignore file all we can do is guess what you've done.

@jonrsharpe :  I have already added all files in the .gitignore file. The issue we are having ignore files not getting removed from commit changes list. somehow .gitignore not reflected
